# asp.net mvc3 RouteLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have just upgraded my mvc2 app to mvc3. And the routelink stopped working. any clue??

Global

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Category",                                           
            "category/{cat}/{subcat}/{page}/{viewall}",                                 
            new 
            {
                controller = "Category",
                action = "Index",
                cat = UrlParameter.Optional,
                subcat = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = UrlParameter.Optional,
                viewall = UrlParameter.Optional
            }  
        );
```

View

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("Women's", "Category", new { cat = "Women", subcat = "" })%>
```

This is how it renders

```
<a href="">Women's</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a regression bug, as explained by Phil Haack [ http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx ]

Comment: Actually a bug in ASP.NET routing, not just MVC.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. You can have only one optional parameter and this parameter should be the last one in your route definition. So `cat`, `subcat` and `page` cannot be optional. You need to supply their values:

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("Women's", "Category", new { 
    cat = "Women", 
    subcat = "somesubcat", 
    page = "123"  
})%>
```

In ASP.NET MVC 3 this rule was enforced.

Consider the following urls:

```
category/1
category/1/2/
category/1/2/3
category/1/2/3/4
```

Only the last two urls are possible because it's the only case where the route parameters could be mapped to their corresponding values without ambiguity.

Comment: Any idea on why this was enforced? I can see that many people would have a possibility of multiple optional parameters. Can this be mimicked then using multiple routes - each one being a 'sub-route' with the extra optional parameter? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think it would also be a nice thing if this is a rule, that you get an exception from MVC when registering routes with multiple optional parameters

Comment: Added my own answer, as it isn't actually normal, it is a bug.