# ASP.NET MVC3 RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How i can get only link string from `@HTMl.RouteLink`.
I don't want return `<a>` tag, i want only result route link string (/etc/20/etc ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx).Action() method with overload specific for your needs

```
Url.Action("List")
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `Url.RouteUrl(...)` and not `Url.Action(...)` ? Since you're asking about a route link, and not an action link?

Comment: Also, just want to mention this thread too in case you do use RouteUrl/RouteLink - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788267/asp-net-mvc3-routelink. You can only have one optional parameter in MVC3 it appears.